# Adjoint operator in the basis with metric matrix g

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's suppose I have a metric matrix g, how do I prove that the matrix representation of the adjoint linear operator $M^{\dagger}$ equals $g^{-1}Mg$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the adjoint operator $M^\dagger$ is the operator such that $<Ma,b> = <a, M^\dagger b>$ for all $a, b$, where with $<a,b>$ I mean the scalar (or inner) product between $a$ and $b$. Which is $agb$. 
Point of this is that applying first $M$ and then $g$ is the same than applying first $g$ and then $M^\dagger$.

So we have $g M^\dagger = M g $, hence $g^{-1}gM^\dagger = g^{-1}Mg$ which is $M^\dagger = g^{-1}Mg$

Comment: The explanation and algebra looks alright, but could you show the step of how to get from <M a,b> to M g. I have been trying to do with the unit vector and getting stuck as to how to bring the operator around. Maybe I am overlooking a small algebraic detail.